# Is there a way to prevent a parent container from scrolling when a child node is focused?

Tags: javascript, html, focus, dom-events

Situation: there is a fixed-height parent div with `overflow: auto` and enough child "line-item" divs of sufficient height to trigger the presence of scrollbars. Each of these child divs has tabindex=-1 so can be programmatically focused.

When any of these child divs is programmatically focused, the default behavior of the browser (in this case, Chrome 55) seems to be to scroll the parent div to center the newly-focused child. Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Followup: can't just reset ScrollTop, because it needs to be able to scroll otherwise. I suppose I could cache the previous scroll value and OnFocus on the child node, restore the previous scroll offset in a SetTimeout :(

Comment: I have updated my solution below to keep the existing offset, instead of always returning to the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: as of 2021, all evergreen browsers support e.g. `element.focus({ preventScroll: true })` as an option.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. There is not a way to prevent the parent element from scrolling to the focused element (that I know of). However, you can undo the scrolling by scrolling the parent element back to the top. Done correctly, it won't be noticeable to the user.

To do this, anytime you programmatically focus an element, retrieve the current scroll offset of the focused element's parent node and set `scrollTop` to that offset.

```js
var children = document.getElementsByClassName('child')

for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  children[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault
    var focused = document.getElementById('focus')
    var focusedParent = focused.parentNode
    var savedOffset = focusedParent.scrollTop
    focused.focus();
    focused.parentNode.scrollTop = savedOffset;
  })
}
```

```css
.parent {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" tabIndex="-1">1</div>
  <div class="child" tabIndex="-1">2</div>
  <div class="child" tabIndex="-1">3</div>
  <div class="child" tabIndex="-1">4</div>
  <div class="child" tabIndex="-1">5</div>
  <div class="child" tabIndex="-1">6</div>
  <div class="child" tabIndex="-1">7</div>
  <div class="child" tabIndex="-1">8</div>
  <div class="child" tabIndex="-1" id="focus">9</div>
  <div class="child" tabIndex="-1">10</div>
</div>
```

Here's the working demo on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/brettdewoody/pen/bgGMRN).

Comment: Thank you for this -- forgot to come back at the time but this is what I ended up doing :)